# Loading null values with CsvDataFileLoader in dbunit

Tags: dbunit

We are using the `CsvDataFileLoader` to load in our reference data like so:

```
new InsertIdentityOperation(DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT)
            .execute(connection,
                    new CsvDataFileLoader().load("/sql/ReferenceData/"));
```

Is there anyway to put `null` values into a csv that is loaded into our db.

I don't think there is, I would imagine that , `null` and `NULL` would all get interpreted as their string values.

Has anyone managed to do this or know of a work around for this problem?

Comment: It's possible with the XML loader but not the CSV as far as I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CsvDataFileLoader` uses `CsvURLProducer` to load and parse the data.

In that class on Line 145 for dbunit 2.4.8 you see the following:

```
if (CsvDataSetWriter.NULL.equals(row[col])) {
    row[col] = null;
}
```

`CsvDataSetWriter.NULL` contains the string `"null"` therefore your assumption that null would get interpreted as a string value appears to be incorrect and you should use this in your CSV.

Of course this means that you can't have the string `"null"` in your fields but I'm sure this isn't often required.

Comment: According to that same file (CsvDataSetWriter) there is a quote constant so you could put `"null"` in your csv and I would assume it would use the string null.